# make a new csv with certain conditions in R

Tags: r, csv

I am a newbie to R. I couldn't figure out a way to do this,

I have two csv files. a.csv has the data in the following format (name is unique in this file)

```
name, count
abc,  100
bcf,  234
```

b.csv has the data in the following format (id is unique, name can occur multiple times),

```
id,  name1, count
123, abc,   29
33,  bcg,   56
145, abc,   45
```

now I need to create a new csv file for each "name" in a.csv containing the rows of the same name in "name1" of the second csv files

for example

```
abc.csv should have
123, abc, 29
145, abc, 45

bcf.csv should be empty for the given files
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with some basic filtering and one loop. For instance, reproducing your example:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = data_frame(name = c("abc", "bcf"), count = c(100, 234))
df2 = data_frame(id = c(123, 33, 145), name1 = c("abc", "bcg", "abc"), count = c(29, 56, 45))
```

You can loop on the unique names of the first file and for all of them filter the second data frame and write the results in the folder you want

```
x = lapply(unique(df1$name), function(tmp_name){
  tmp_df = filter(df2, name1 == tmp_name)
  write.csv(tmp_df, file = paste0("~/", tmp_name, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  return(tmp_df)
})
```

This piece of code will write .csv files in your root folder (you can change this modifying the ~ into the folder you want) named abc.csv, bcf.csv etc. It will also save the results into the object x that is a list of dataframes

Answer (score 1):

Try this first:

```
unique(data1[name %in% data2[,name1],])
```

This is useful when you are merging two data sets with non unique keys. With some small changes on the results, you should have your answer.

Comment: What does this answer do differently than your other one?

Comment: @Paul, It was a simple mistake.

Comment: Could you add some context. Right now your answer is just a single line of code. More context makes it easier for the OP and other people to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = data_frame(name = c("abc", "bcf"), count = c(100, 234))
df2 = data_frame(id = c(123, 33, 145), name1 = c("abc", "bcg", "abc"), count = c(29, 56, 45))

result = 
  df2 %>%
  rename(name = name1, count2 = count) %>%
  semi_join(df1) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  do(sub_df = {
    write.csv(.,
              sprintf("/tmp/%s.csv", first(.$name)),
              row.names = FALSE)
    .
  })
```